# Android Aeris maps not working properly

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on **Aeris** -- an Android API for map display. It has Google map inside and should be easy to set location and add layers.

Now, I can see the google map produced, while my sentences about setting location, zoom level and layer seem not working at all. Since the map occurs, the map fragment is actually fetched, and I guess there should be some problem in my fragment part.

```
public class MapFragment extends MapViewFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AerisEngine.initWithKeys(this.getString(R.string.aeris_client_id), this.getString(R.string.aeris_client_secret), "com.example.android.forecastsearch");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        mapView = (AerisMapView)view.findViewById(R.id.aerisfragment_map);
        mapView.init(savedInstanceState, AerisMapType.GOOGLE);
        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("Lat"));
        Double lng = Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("Lng"));
        mapView.moveToLocation(new LatLng(lat, lng), 9);
        mapView.addLayer(AerisTile.RADAR);
        return view;
    }
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped this guy with debugging, and found out that it was because the method was not being called. Since there was another package, where there was a MapFragment, after we replaced the one above, the problem was solved.